# Python - extract value from key-value pair

Tags: python, django

lots of googling done but I'm stumped.  I know this is simple but I can't seem to find the format to retrieve the value from a key/value pair when I supply the key in python.   I'm using django --

```
images = Article.objects.filter(pk=self.ID).values("image1", "image2", "image3")
```

fills images with the following object:

```
<QuerySet [{'image3': u'', 'image2': u'', 'image1': u'articleImages/django-allauth.png'}]>
```

So my question is --- I want get get the value for "image1" how do I get that!! I really really really appreciate your help -

I want something like

```
image1 = images['image1'] ## clearly this doesn't work
```

Comment: Try `image1 = images[0]['image1']`.

Comment: `for i in images: print i.image1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
d = [{'image3': u'', 'image2': u'', 'image1': u'articleImages/django-allauth.png'}]


d[0]['image1']
```

Output:

```
u'articleImages/django-allauth.png'
```

Comment: OMG Totally worked.  Thanks so much -- I'll try the flat implementation too but this answers the question directly.  I used: image1 = images[0]['image1'] and that was the winner.  I wasn't comprehending the 2D nature of the variable.   Thanks again you guys are awesome

Answer (score 1):

Use [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
# will return ['articleImages/django-allauth.png']
images = Article.objects.filter(pk=self.ID).values_list("image1", flat=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

QuerySet seems to be a list of dict, so perhaps the following will work:

```
image1 = list(images)[0]['image1']
```